# What oyster species is 砵酒焗生蠔?

Tags: chinese-cuisine, ingredient-selection, seafood

[Picture from Hong Kong restaurant](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-tang-court-p5828427). Hence oyster can be bought in H.K.  What oyster species I buy to make this 砵酒焗蠔, which means Port Wine Baked Oyster?

[image]

[Another picture](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-tang-court-p12507831). I won't post more two, but here's [another view](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-tang-court-p12379167).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of oysters used in _ are **Hiroshima oysters**
Although many books say you can use any oyster but restaurants say Hiroshima oysters.